# Accessing Server path in C#

Tags: c#, windows, file, service, windows-services

I need to copy the file from the server path to local path. Below is the C# code i used to access the server path.

```
 NetworkCredential ntCredential = new NetworkCredential(User, Password);
 CredentialCache cCredential = new CredentialCache();
 cCredential.Add(new Uri(Server), "Basic", ntCredential);
 DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(ServerPath);
 FileInfo[] filelistinfo = d.GetFiles();
```

This code works fine if i create it as normal console application. But if i use the same code in Windows Service it is throwing me an error "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." 
I gave my Server path as \vmmson\Data\
Anyone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: What is the user your service runs on ?

Comment: My service runs on Local System Account. I also tried by running the service on Network Service Account. But i am getting same error.